# express.js retrieve username from mysql database doesn't redirect to signin page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to retrieve username from mysql database, the below code can successfully retrieve the username. However, when err occurs, code doesn't redirect to /signin. The page redirect to /admin instead. Though, if I add

> res.redirect('/signin')

just before the last curly bracket, it will redirect to the signin page, but it won't able to retrieve the username.

I want it to redirect to signin page, how?

```js
const connection = require('./connection')

const signin = (req, res) => {

    var email = req.body.email
    var password = req.body.password
    let queryStr = `select username from users where email='${email}' and password='${password}'`

    return connection.query(queryStr, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/signin')
                     
        } else {
            req.session.email = email
            res.json(rows[0])
        }
    })
    
}

module.exports = signin
```

I think it has to do with async because the code execute the last line then go back to the else statement. I think that's why it goes to /admin page instead. but not fixed yet.

---

connection.js

```js
const mysql=require('mysql')

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'root',
    database:'essencejoin',
})

connection.connect()

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err
  
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
  })

module.exports=connection
```

Comment: The backtick (`) in your query, is that a typo?

Comment: no, it's template literal

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You're Query is correct, But query doesn't return any rows. So if user not found on username table. It needs to signin page(This is your question correct?), For that you have to update the code like following,

```
const connection = require('./connection')

const signin = (req, res) => {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    let queryStr = `select username from users where email='${email}' and password='${password}'`;

    return connection.query(queryStr, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/signin');           
        } else if(!rows.length) {
            res.redirect('/signin');
        }else {
            req.session.email = email;
            res.json(rows[0]);
        }
    })

}

module.exports = signin
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks your code is being executed after you have returned it. You can use promisified version of the same code.

use [mysql-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql). this is promisified wrapper around the same library you are using. then Your code will look something like this:

// install mysql-promise

```
npm i mysql-promise
```

connection.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql-promise");

async function getDBConn() {
  const connection =  mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "essencejoin"
  });
  await connection.connect();
  return connection;
}

module.exports = getDBConn;
```

then use it like this:

//signin.js

```
const signin = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const connection = getDBConn();
  let queryStr = `select username from users where email='${email}' and password='${password}'`;
  try {
    await connection.query(queryStr);
    req.session.email = email;
    res.json(rows[0]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.redirect("/signin");
  }
};

module.exports = signin;
```

disclaimer: I have not tested this, even if this does not work this should give you a fair idea how to make it work

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing too much about your project, I think you want to look into adding a status code with the express redirect.

```
 index(req, res, next) {
    topicQueries.getAllTopics((err, topics) => {
      if (err) {
        res.redirect(500, "static/index");
      } else {
        res.render("topics/index", { topics });
      }
    });
  }
```

Something like that. Also, look out for other simple mistakes in your project, that may cause this, that deal with Express.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: Make sure that err is coming back as true as well. If err is not true, your IF statement will never run. So ensure the callback function satisfies this.

Comment: I tried to enter wrong password and username, however, the err doesn't do a thing, I tried to console.log(err) but nothing shows, just go straight to /admin page. I guess wrong info proves err is not true. Adding "res.redirect('/signin')" just before the last curly bracket will redirect to the /signin page but retrieving username no longer work. So I'm thinking is more aboiut logic of the code

Comment: Post your connection query function.

Comment: const mysql=require('mysql')

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'root',
    database:'essencejoin',
})

connection.connect()

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err
  
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
  })

module.exports=connection